# Oozie job configuration app directory not found on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, workflow, hdfs, cloudera, oozie

I installed a pseudo-distributed version of Cloudera on my Linux box, and ran some simple MapReduce examples with success.  However, I'm trying to get Oozie to work, and am completely baffled by the errors I am receiving when attempting to execute a simple job workflow:

```
tim@phocion:~$ oozie version
Oozie client build version: 3.1.3-cdh4.0.1
```

Copy the pre-packaged examples to HDFS and execute, per the documentation:

```
tim@phocion:~$ oozie job -oozie http://phocion:11000/oozie -config /user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run
Error: E0504 : E0504: App directory [hdfs://phocion:8020/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce] does not exist
```

Check to see if the file exists:

```
tim@phocion:~$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce
Found 3 items
-rwxr-xr-x   1 tim tim        995 2012-10-03 14:47 /user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties
drwxrwxr-x   - tim tim       4096 2012-10-03 14:47 /user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce/lib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 tim tim       2559 2012-10-03 14:47 /user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce/workflow.xml
```

It does.  Can I connect to phocion:8020?

```
tim@phocion:~$ telnet phocion 8020
Trying 127.0.1.1...
Connected to phocion.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I can.  So, basically, I'm at a total loss as to what this error is trying to tell me - the folder very much does exist.  I'm assuming the error is too vague to fully communicate what the issue is, but I've found virtually nothing out there that could point me in the right direction.

I can also replicate this error with other 3rd party tutorials.

Spent much time pouring through configuration files to the point of not wanting to look at a computer ever again.  Maybe I'm over thinking the issue here, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Adding the full job.properties (not too different from the default):

```
nameNode=hdfs://phocion:8020
jobTracker=phocion:8021
queueName=default
examplesRoot=examples
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}/apps/map-reduce
outputDir=map-reduce
```

MORE EDITS: I get the same exact error when the folder DOES NOT exist, and after I put if back into hdfs.  Last-ditch idea that its a permissions issue, chmod 777 still gets the same error. Full HDFS path passed on the command line doesn't fix the issue.  Running it under oozie and even root accounts don't work:

```
tim@phocion:~$ oozie job -oozie http://phocion:11000/oozie -run -config /home/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -Doozie.wf.application.path=hdfs://phocion:8020/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce
Error: E0504 : E0504: App directory [hdfs://phocion:8020/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce] does not exist
tim@phocion:~$ hdfs dfs -put examples/ /user/tim/
12/10/04 13:26:43 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
tim@phocion:~$ oozie job -oozie http://phocion:11000/oozie -run -config /home/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -Doozie.wf.application.path=hdfs://phocion:8020/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce
Error: E0504 : E0504: App directory [hdfs://phocion:8020/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce] does not exist
tim@phocion:~$ hdfs dfs -chmod -R 777 /user/tim/examples/
12/10/04 13:28:16 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
tim@phocion:~$ oozie job -oozie http://phocion:11000/oozie -run -config /home/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -Doozie.wf.application.path=hdfs://phocion:8020/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce
Error: E0504 : E0504: App directory [hdfs://phocion:8020/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce] does not exist
tim@phocion:~$ sudo -u oozie oozie job -oozie http://phocion:11000/oozie -run -config /home/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -Doozie.wf.application.path=hdfs://phocion:8020/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce
[sudo] password for tim: 
Error: E0504 : E0504: App directory [hdfs://phocion:8020/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce] does not exist
tim@phocion:~$ sudo -u root oozie job -oozie http://phocion:11000/oozie -run -config /home/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -Doozie.wf.application.path=hdfs://phocion:8020/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce
Error: E0504 : E0504: App directory [hdfs://phocion:8020/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce] does not exist
```

Should this command work in theory?

```
tim@phocion:~$ hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://phocion:8020/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce
ls: `hdfs://phocion:8020/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce': No such file or directory
```

This shows up in hadoop-hdfs logs after executing the oozie command:

```
2012-10-04 13:50:00,152 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Starting log segment at 113297
2012-10-04 13:50:00,874 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.TransferFsImage: Opening connection to http://localhost.localdomain:50090/getimage?getimage=1&txid=113296&storageInfo=-40:2092007576:0:cluster8
2012-10-04 13:50:00,875 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hdfs (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2012-10-04 13:50:00,876 WARN org.mortbay.log: /getimage: java.io.IOException: GetImage failed. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:395)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:234)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:307)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:324)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
```

Comment: As noted at the "Running the Examples" section of the Oozie docs at http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/oozie/DG_Examples.html#Running_the_Examples, can you try passing a proper local path to -config at the CLI instead of a HDFS-style path? The -config expects the properties to be a locally available, configurable file, not inside the HDFS.

Comment: @Harsh-J Appreciate the help.  I had -config point to the config file outside HDFS.  Same error:

 
tim@phocion:~$ oozie job -oozie http://phocion:11000/oozie -config /home/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run
Error: E0504 : E0504: App directory [hdfs://phocion:8020/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce] does not exist

Comment: Can you check the Hadoop config (`/etc/hadoop/conf/*-site.xml`) for the following property: `fs.defaultFS`  >> that's the prefix used whenever you don't explicitly mention "hdfs://host:port/home/dir/" or "hdfs://HA_alias/home/dir/"

Comment: BTW, you should check the config on your edge node (the one you are running HDFS command-line on) but also on the node running Oozie server, if different, and also  _all_ cluster nodes that might be running the Oozie actions...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to HarshJ's comment, check your error message:

```
Error: E0504 : E0504: App directory [hdfs://phocion:8020/user/tim/examples/apps/demo] does not exist
```

And the hadoop fs -ls listing you provided:

```
/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce/
```

And play spot the difference:

```
/user/tim/examples/apps/demo
/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce/
```

try configuring as follows:

```
oozie.wf.application.path=/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. My fault - I was testing two different examples and mixed up pasting the output here.  I get the error both with map-reduce/ and demo/, and they both do exist.  I also tried modifying the application path like you suggested to many different paths - both HDFS and not.  Same error.

Comment: Can you paste the contents of your job.properties file into your original question? have you tried `oozie job -run -Doozie.wf.application.path=/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce`

Comment: Same error passing in param via command line:
tim@phocion:~$ oozie job -oozie http://phocion:11000/oozie -run -Doozie.wf.application.path=/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce  -config /home/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties
Error: E0504 : E0504: App directory [/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce] does not exist

Comment: I know on my versions of oozie, i need to fully qualify the app path, have you tried `oozie job -run -Doozie.wf.application.path=hdfs://phocion:8020/user/tim/examples/apps/map-reduce ...`

Comment: Thanks Chris - updated above.  Passing in the full HDFS path on the command line yields the same error.  I cannot do an "ls" on that full HDFS path via hdfs, however.

Comment: so if you don't fully qualify the hdfs path, `hadoop fs -ls` works? - what's the contents of your core-site.xml list for the `fs.default.name`?

Comment: Chris - correct, using the fully qualified hdfs:// path with "hdfs -ls" results in file not found.  Using the regular Unix path is not a problem.  `fs.default.name` is "_hdfs://phocion:8020_".  I have -put many files in HDFS, but if you look at the **/metrics** endpoint on the NamedNode, it says 0KB total in storage.  I'm beginning to think this stems from an issue with Ubuntu's /etc/hosts configuration and how the different CDH4 services use 127.0.1.1 and 127.0.0.1.  Could someone post an example of a working hosts file?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue and got it fixed by exporting the correct oozie url.

To export you should use the below command

```
export OOZIE_URL=http://someip:11000/oozie
```

To get this oozie url you need to use hue to connect you cluster and navigate to Workflows where you can find a tab called `oozie`. Inside this you should see **gauges** where a lot of properties will be listed. Look for the property **oozie.servers**.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is to `-copyFromLocal` the examples folder to the location specified in the jobs config.